# Are questions about hooking up AV equipment on topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently there have been some questions about hooking up audio/video equipment, specifically these:

- [What options are there for smart TV to connect to db15 dolby 5.1 speakers?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78071/what-options-are-there-for-smart-tv-to-connect-to-db15-dolby-5-1-speakers)
- [Bose Acoustimass subwoofer and a Yamaha RXV870 receiver?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78155/bose-acoustimass-subwoofer-and-a-yamaha-rxv870-receiver)

Are these types of questions on topic? If not, what close reason should be used?

Comment: For what its worth, I think the first question can be have a generic, widely useful answer, while the second is too narrow/brand specific, and thus off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these fall in the "small appliance" category or "brand specific advice" and should be closed. They would be considered on topic in the old gadgets SE, but that didn't survive due to too many questions about specific devices without enough experts that could cover each individual brand. I feel the [home-theater](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-theater) tag should be limited to generic advice (non brand specific) and preferably for parts of the install that may be included when the home is purchased or apply to the structure of the home (wiring through walls, builtin speakers, wall mounts for a TV).